# htaccess RewriteRule with a variable not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

This rule takes us to the error page
`RewriteRule ^latest/([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ latest?auth=$1 [NC,L]`

I have the following in my .htaccess file

```
# BEGIN - Allow Sucuri Services
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteRule ^sucuri-(.*)\.php$ - [L]
</IfModule>
# END - Allow Sucuri Services

<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +MultiViews

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.xxxxx.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.xxxxx.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ci_index.php?/$1 [L]

## Remove php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php$
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^latest/([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ latest?auth=$1 [NC,L]
```

With the following rule

```
RewriteRule ^latest/([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ latest?auth=$1 [NC,L]
```

Trying to achieve the following:

```
https://www.xxxxx.com/latest?auth=US-mobile-county
```

to

```
https://www.xxxxx.com/latest/US-mobile-county
```

Comment: Please define "not working", as it can mean anything. Also define what you mean by "variable" here. What do you want it to do and what actually happens? Give us some examples. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You need to state what URL(s) you are requesting and what the intended outcome is. There are a number of issues with the directives you've posted (directives in the wrong order, use of MultiViews, etc.), but it's also not clear exactly what it is you are trying to do. eg. Presumably the intention is to rewrite to `latest.php`, not `latest`?

Answer (score 1):

> This rule takes us to the error page `RewriteRule ^latest/([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ latest?auth=$1 [NC,L]`

You've not stated precisely what "error page" you are referring to? Or what is expected to handle this request. This directive is not correct by itself, so it's not immediately clear what it is you are trying to do. I'm assuming the intention is to rewrite to `latest.php` (not `latest` as suggested by this rule, and mentioned later in the question) - since this would seem to be the only reason to implement such a rule (and your question is tagged `php`). By rewriting to `latest` only you are dependent on other directives appending the `.php` extension - and therein lies a conflict.

There are a number of issues with the directives as posted that is preventing  this from working. Notably, the rules are in the wrong order and the use of `MultiViews` (probably in an attempt to get extensionless URLs working) is compounding matters. In fact, it doesn't look like the rule in question is actually being processed at all.

Without `MultiViews`, and due to the order of the directives, a request of the form `/latest/something` would be rewritten to `/ci_index.php?/latest/something` (presumably a CodeIgniter front-controller) which I would guess would result in a CI generated 404 response. However, since `MultiViews` has been enabled mod_negotiation first "rewrites" the request to `/latest.php/something`, which doesn't match any of your rules so either results in a 404 (depending on your server config) or calls `latest.php` but without any URL parameter, which presumably causes your script to fail?

> `https://www.xxxxx.com/latest/US-mobile-county`

Also, note that your example URL contains hyphens (`-`), but the regex in your directive (ie. `^latest/([A-Za-z0-9]+)$`) does not permit hyphens so it wouldn't have matched anyway.

Try the following instead, replacing everything after the `ErrorDocument` directive:

```
# Disable MultiViews
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on

# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Redirect non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Rewrite "/latest/something" to "/latest.php?auth=something"
RewriteRule ^latest/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ latest.php?auth=$1 [L]

# Allow extensionless PHP URLs to work
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [L]

# Front-controller
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ci_index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Note that I've reversed the order of the directives so that the rule in question is now first and the CI front-controller is now last. The order of the directives in `.htaccess` is important.

Since you had enabled `MultiViews` (now disabled in the above), your rule to enable PHP extensionless URLs (that you had labelled "Remove php extension") was not actually being used at all (unless you had directories or files that contained dots, other than that used to delimit the file extension).

Comment: I am using the above in my .htaccess file

The issue that I am facing is whenever I try to open the file https://www.example.com/world-data it opens the folder - https://www.example.com/world-data/index.php instead of https://www.example.com/world-data.php

How do I prevent the folder being opened instead of the file?

Comment: This has now been addressed in a separate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76146519/htaccess-php-file-first-and-then-folder @GurusGuru